# MS sql Case Statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this select statement and what i am trying to accomplish is when AuditLog is null then set 'Enabled' but my issues is i am not sure how to handle it when it is not NULL, i want to be able to get the data from AuditLog into AuditLogEnabled when it is not null. I have tried adding an else, but have not been able to get it to work. can someone show me the correct way to write this.

```
select FirstName,AuditLog,
CASE WHEN AuditLog IS NULL THEN 'Enabled' END AS AuditLogEnabled
from UserDetail
where FirstName = 'test'
```

Comment: Not getting it to work -- are you getting an error or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend doing it using COALESCE -

```
SELECT FirstName,AuditLog,COALESCE(AuditLog,'Enabled') AS AuditLogEnabled
FROM UserDetail
WHERE FirstName = 'test'
```

Reason for using COALESCE - 
ISNULL is dependent to data type of the first argument. And sometimes it leads to data truncation - 
For Example -

```
DECLARE @value VARCHAR(5)
SELECT 'Using COALESCE', COALESCE(@value, 'My String')
SELECT 'Using ISNULL', ISNULL(@value, 'My String')
```

Result -

```
Using COALESCE  My String
Using ISNULL    My St
```

This could be serious problem. Don't use ISNULL unless you are sure about datatype and its length.

Comment: Serious question. In what scenario are you unsure of a datatype and length in SQL?

Comment: @SpectralGhost Firstly, let me make it clear by unsure I don't mean not knowing about data type defined. I mean be sure the value in second argument will fit within data length defined for first. Above is just the simple example. If you have some other column from some other table as second argument for `ISNULL`, then it is better if you verified the data length first or simply you can just use `COALESCE`. And in many case like when your table is created using `SELECT * INTO` or during some string manipulations, it is quiet hard to predict that.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a case, but in this simple situation, I prefer `ISNULL()`

```
select FirstName,AuditLog,ISNULL(AuditLog,'Enabled') AS AuditLogEnabled
from UserDetail
where FirstName = 'test'
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as AuditLog is a string, then something like this should work:

```
select FirstName,
CASE WHEN AuditLog IS NULL THEN 'Enabled' ELSE AuditLog END AS AuditLogEnabled
from UserDetail
where FirstName = 'test'
```